# Received duplicate emails SSRS Subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-subscription

I have created the SSRS Subscription in the SSRS 2016 and run this subscription automatically using SQL Server Agent job. The subscription was working fine but from last 3 days, all recipients received duplicate emails. I have checked the report server logs in Catalog, Subscription, Schedule tables but didn't find the duplicate report or subscription run entry. Also, checked the report server logs file but didn't find the duplicate entry. I still don't know why these are resending. Any advice?

Comment: How is your report subscription being triggered? Is *"using SQL Server Agent job"* a regular subscription or an SSIS job?

Comment: Using SQL Server Agent Job.

Comment: This has just started happening for me too. We have around 100 subscriptions which have been working for years (SSRS 2012) and some of them are being received twice. This started on the 9th of October. I also see no duplicates in any tables and the logs show single subscriptions firing. The only place I can see the duplicates is in the sent folder for the office 365 email address we SMPT with. The duplicate emails are sent at exactly the same time.

Comment: This thread explains it better   
[link](https://forums.iis.net/p/1239526/2143830.aspx?p=True&t=636748712255778814)     And it links to this Reddit thread  [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/9hqrbj/duplicate_emails_coming_from_iis_relay_to_o365/?sort=new)